# Spring JPA Query Bug

Tags: java, spring

I have a bug that is very strange.

I'm storing some inputData in the database:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("all", all);
params.put("pageable", pageable);

myObj.setInputData(params);

...
then repo.save(myObj);
```

[image]

But when I query `findByTestId` I get this error:

> > java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.domain.Sort$Order.()    at
> > java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)    at
> > java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553)     at
> > org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:146)

This is my repo:

```
 public interface DataRepository extends MongoRepository<Data, String> {

   Optional<Data> findByTestId(String testid);

 }
```

If I delete the pageable from the `inputData` it works fine again. Why my HashMap is being used in the query? How do I fix this?

All I want is to get the inputData again so I can use it in the query.

**EDIT: I ALSO TRIED TO USE AN OBJECT INSTEAD OF THE HASHMAP BUT I GET THE SAME PROBLEM**

Comment: please show `Data` class used in repository

Comment: @MarcStroebel Data class has a property called inputData that is Map<String, Object>. Nothing special

Comment: Related: [org.springframework.data.domain.Sort why the error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64861604/3744182).

Comment: So the problem must be in `pageable` ... payload... (Case sensitivity: order vs. Order)